# connecting two vertex (F) not working?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to connect a vertex from one curve to the vertex from another duplicated curve. The command does not make a segment between vertex. If I pick 2 the vertex from the same curve I can. I am wondering if I can not connect after I duplicate the curve.

Comment: there should be no problem, except with the inner vertices, you can't join them

Comment: I did it three times till it worked. It seems that something went wrong with the duplicate command and did not take the two curves as the same entity to join their vertexes. Did you experienced that?

Comment: no it never happened to me, weird

Comment: Oddly, ( IMO) you can have different spline types in the same Curve object. Those can't be joined, either...